# Autowiring DataSource NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, autowired

```
 public class DAOManager {
      @Autowired
      private DataSource dataSource;
 .....
```

When I go to run the above, dataSource remains as null.

How I've configured the bean in web-context.xml:

```
<!-- Datasource (database) bean -->
<bean id="dataSource"
     class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
     <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
     <property name="url" value="XXXXX" />
     <property name="username" value="XXXX" />
     <property name="password" value="XXXX" />
</bean>
```

I feel like there's something I need to be adding to my web-context.xml to add the DAOManager class into its jurisdiction.. am I right with this? Sorry, first time Spring MVC user.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you have a bean definition for `DAOManager`?  Spring has to instantate it as well in order to apply autowiring.

Comment: @JimGarrison - I do not, no. I'm not really sure where to do this, either.

Comment: Let me know if neither the injection or `@Configurable` approaches I describe in my writeup looks like it'll work. Usually, reorganizing the code a bit so that everything's injected is the best long-term approach, but DAO is one common pattern where `@Configurable` is really useful (though usually with Active Record; a full `DAOManager`-type class is usually injected).

Comment: @chrylis - I'm reading through it all now, there's a lot to read/get my head around. I'll get back to you in a bit.

Comment: Are you running this in a container such as Tomcat or JBoss? If not you will need to have a top-level Spring-aware class to initiate the whole wiring process.

Comment: Yeah, there's a good bit going on under the hood in Spring. It's powerful, but there are a few gotchas with all the moving parts. Short version is that unless you use AspectJ, Spring doesn't know about anything you call `new` on.

Answer (score 0):

You ask:

> I feel like there's something I need to be adding to my
>   web-context.xml to add the DAOManager class into its jurisdiction.. am
>   I right with this?

You are right :)

Answer (score 0):

Put @Repository above your class DAOManager and see.

Though idealy the configuration you did, seems fine, and is a simple DI, and should work fine as it is now.

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
<bean id="daoManager" class="DAOManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add to your spring xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.your.package" />
```

Comment: This won't make any difference, since the `DAOManager` isn't any sort of Spring bean.

Comment: <context:component-scan base-package="com.dauntless" /> <- Added this, and no difference.

Comment: I assume that you can't annotate DAOManager?